# How to permanently Set/change the Limits in Solaris 10 system wide

Tags: solaris, ulimit

I received email from oracle to change the limit on solaris 10 server to make oracle application work,

unfortunately i have no experience in Solaris, so need assistance

Values will be like below

```
A00110 This rule verifies that the ulimit settings are adequate Oracle Database 11g R2. The recommended values are not less than: 
ulimit(TIME) = unlimited
ulimit(FILE) = unlimited
ulimit(DATA) = 1048576
Soft ulimit(NOFILES) = 1024
Hard ulimit(NOFILES) = 65536
ulimit(VMEMORY) = 4194304
and not more than 
Soft ulimit(STACK) = 10240
Hard ulimit(STACK) = 32768
VmemoryNotDefined 
StackHardUnlimited Review the ulimit settings: 
Set the hard ulimit(STACK) to a maximum of 32768 
ulimit(VMEMORY) is not defined
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/21417/how-to-set-ulimits-in-solaris-10

Comment: There are multiple limits ike (Time,File,Data,NoFiles,Vmemory,Stack) any idea where to get all this information in solaris , or can this be done using /etc/system file ?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2358615?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: ya already checked this one not much helpful

Comment: I will look around. I thought Oracle 11 included a shell script you run as root during installation that edits all the config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising the global file descriptor limit is not recommended as this could make 32 bit programs fail unless they have knowledge about how to use file descriptors > 255, see: `enable_extended_FILE_stdio(3C)`.

So it may be better to just call the oracle data base via a shell script that first does the needed `ulimit` calls to set up the limits and then call the database.

Let me show a typical Solaris limit set that could be retrieved with the Bourne Shell (as in my example). Note that using `ksh93` is not helpful here as ksh93 includes information from other resources that are not settable. This is the default on Solaris:

```
LC_ALL=C ulimit -aSH
-t: time(seconds) unlimited:unlimited
-f: file(blocks) unlimited:unlimited
-d: data(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
-s: stack(kbytes) 10240:unlimited
-c: coredump(blocks) unlimited:unlimited
-n: nofiles(descriptors) 256:65536
-v: memory(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
```

As you see, all default values are higher than the required values except for the open file descriptors. I am not sure whether the stack hard limit should be reduced.

If you like to modify the values, write a shell script and enter this:

```
ulimit -nS 1024
```

This raises the soft file descriptor limit to 1024 and results in a new limit:

```
-n: nofiles(descriptors) 1024:65536
```

If you need to reduce the hard stack limit, also enter:

```
ulimit -sH 32768
```

This reduced the hard stack limit to 32 MB and results in:

```
-s: stack(kbytes) 10240:32768
```

After that, enter the command to start the oracle data base to the script and then run this script.

Comment: Or set the limits for a dedicated oracle (or oracle app) user.

Comment: That's what i want but i have no idea how to do that on Solaris. Any reference to document will be helpful

Comment: I enhanced the answer, is this sufficient?